# Why is $\int \vert g(u) - g(v) \vert dF(u)$ = $\int\int 1[x\in ((g(u),g(v)) ] dx dF(u)$

Tags: integration

when $1$ denotes the indicator function.

It looks something like the fundamental theorem of calculus to me, but the indicator function jumps so I'm not sure it is applicable?

Note regarding the Hypotheses:  I'm okay with an answer assuming whatever Hypotheses this is true under. Im interested though in Particular about when $F$ is a CDF and $g$ is a continuous function defined on the reals.

Comment: The formula is wrong. LHS should be changed to $\int (g(v)-g(u)^{+} dF(u,v)$.

Comment: Like that, with no clear hypotheses? What kind of functions are $g$ and $F$: where are they defined and how regular (i.e. measurable, continuous, integrable, smooth etc.) are they?

Comment: @AlexM. Sorry. I just saw the step in a proof somewhere and wasn't sure why it was valid. I'm okay with an answer assuming whatever Hypotheses this is true under. Im interested though in Particular about when $F$ is a CDF and $g$ is a continuous function defined on the reals.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \leq b$, you have that $b - a = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(x)dx$ in the usual Lebesgue measure.

As noted by Kavi in a comment, the formula is slightly wrong: when $g(u) > g(v)$, you have that $\mathbb{1}_{(g(u),g(v))} = \mathbb{1}_{\emptyset} = 0$.

Then

$$\int |g(u) - g(v)|dF(u) = \int_{g(u)>g(v)}(g(u)-g(v))dF(u) + \int_{g(v)>g(u)}(g(v)-g(u))dF(u) = \\ =\int_{g(u)>g(v)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{1}_{[g(v),g(u)]}(x)dxdF(u) + \int_{g(v)>g(u)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{1}_{[g(u),g(v)]}(x)dxdF(u) = \\ = \int \int_\mathbb{R} (\mathbb{1}_{[g(v),g(u)]}(x) + \mathbb{1}_{[g(u),g(v)]}(x))dxdF(u) = \int \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{1}_{A(g(u),g(v))}(x) dx dF(u)$$

where $A(t,s) = \begin{cases} [t,s] \text{ if } t \leq s \\ [s,t] \text{ if } s \leq t\end{cases}$.

Note that this works for any measure $dF(u)$, because only $|g(u)-g(v)|$ is manipulated, and that you don't need for $g$ to be continuous, because the manipulation is puntual.